# If $P$ is a submodule of $M$ such that $N\subseteq P \subseteq M$ ,then $P=N$ or $P=M$(If and only if) The $R$-module $M/N$ is simple

Tags: ring-theory

> let $M$ be an $R$-module and let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Show that the tow statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) If $P$ is a submodule of $M$ such that $N\subseteq P \subseteq M$ ,then $P=N$ or $P=M$.
>
> (b) The $R$-module $M/N$ is simple.

Comment: there is a bijection between $P$ with $N\leq P\leq M$ and $P'$ with $0\leq P'\leq M/N$

Comment: As @yoyo says, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem_3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose (a) is true and that (b) is not true. Then there is a non-trivial proper submodule of $M/N$, which can be written as $L/N$, with $L$ a sumbodule of $M$ such that $N \subsetneq L \subsetneq M$. But this contradicts (a). I leave the reverse direction to you.

Comment: (b)=> (a): let (b)holds and if P  is a submodule of M such that N⊆P⊆M, then P/N is a submodule of M/N and since M/N is simple then P/N=M/N or P/N={0} thus (a)holds. (Is my answer make sense?)

Comment: @Fayz: Correct, that's it:)